# Record screen as well as internal audio?

Tags: 14.04, sound, screen, screencast, capture

I'm trying to screen record some videos on a particular site. So far, I have tried `simplevideorecorder`, `recordmydesktop` and `kazam` as well (after browsing several threads here). I can get the screen recorded but no sound is there! I just get a 'ssssh' noise recorded.

Can anyone help me solving this? I haven't plugged anything to the mic jack but headphones are plugged to the audio out jack. I'm running KDE on a ubuntu 14.04 box.

Comment: What address for the site? And another question: are you running pulse audio?

Comment: how do i check if i'm running pulse audio or not sorry? also site is an educational site where i want to keep the video recordings downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to record streaming videos.  This can be done, with sound, through browser add-ons.  In Firefox, mouse over the icons in the top right of the browser window.  Click the one that reads "Open menu."  It's most likely on the far right.  Click Add-ons. Switch to the new tab and look for the search bar with a grayed-out "Seach Add-ons."  In this box, type "video recorder" and click search.  You will be presented with several options.